# Jquery keyup() function not work properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm a beggainer lavel in programming. What is the problem I can not find out. when I change the number. it's not working as I want.

html:

```
<tr>  
<td><?php echo $food ;?></td>  
<td id="price"><?php echo $price ;?></td>  
<td><input type="text" value="1" id="num"></td>  
<td id="total">50</td>  
<td><a href="#">X</a></td>  
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#num').keyup(function(){  
    var price = parseInt($('#price').val());  
    var num = parseInt($('#num').val());  
    price = price * num;  
    $('#total').html(price);
});
```

Comment: `<td>` does not have a value -> `$('#price').val()`, you want to use `.text()` -> `var price = parseInt($('#price').text());`

Answer (score 2):

`<td id="price">` is a table cell and as such, you cannot access its `value` as you are trying to do here

```
var price = parseInt($('#price').val());
```

`.val()` method is intended for `input`, `select`, and `textarea` elements, *not* `td` elements. You have a couple of options based on what you actually want to do. I suggest using `.text` instead of `.val()`.

Also, it is good to note that you need to call `.keyup()` only after the element `#num` has loaded. To guarantee this, use `$(document).ready()`. Full javascript code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#num').keyup(function(){  
        var price = parseInt($('#price').text());  
        var num = parseInt($('#num').val());  
        price = price * num;  
        $('#total').html(price);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your informative Answer. I got it. And my problem is solved :-)

Comment: Yay! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

try wrap you event function in [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), or move them in footer area.

Comment: That's only a part of the problem.

Comment: There isn't really any evidence in the question that this is a problem.  If the OP's JavaScript is after that markup, this won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This won't return anything:

```
$('#price').val() // undefined
```

`#price` is a `td` element.  `td` elements don't have a value.  It does, however, have text:

```
$('#price').text() // the value you echo from PHP
```